# PDF rendering only in presentation mode while using PDF.JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, pdf.js

I have been through with the provided documentation on PDF.js, I am able to render the buttons correctly, but there is something wrong, my pdf is not rendering and background of the page is also white.When I click on the presentation mode,  pdf renders in the full page which is perfect. But not able to understand what possible be wrong with the render thing that it is not rendering on page load.

I am using

```
1.compatibility.js
2.l10n.js
3.pdf.js
4.debugger.js
5.viewer.js
6.metadata.js
7.bidi.js
```

The only warning which I got is

```
The provided value 'moz-chunked-arraybuffer' is not a valid enum value of type XMLHttpRequestResponseType.
```

I am currently not able to understand why most of the issues are still not solved,

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you resolve this?